# Output is not coming in JSON format when NoHandlerFoundException coming

Tags: spring

I am using spring 4.X to develop rest api using annotation configuration. I have added servlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true) to send NoHandlerFoundException. Created one GlobalExceptionHandler to handle all exception. My question is if NoHandlerFoundException occurs than output is not coming in JSON Format. Do i need to add anything in my servlet configuration

Comment: All other exception output is coming in JSON Format.